# Trying to assign a variable as the length of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, variables, declaration

I'm trying to get n specific number of values from the user, to do this I went the easy way and asked the user to enter a specific number of values to be entered.
This amount of values is saved in a variable, for example "*x*":

```
int x;
printf("Enter the number of values to be entered: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
int array[x];
```

So when I try to run the code I get the following message:

**Constant Expression Required**

Why does this happens? How could I fix it?

Comment: This is a `c99` feature both `gcc` and to a point `clang` support it as a extension in non-c99 mode but Visual Studio does not support c99 hence no variable length arrays in visual studio. Are you use visual studio? Can you provide more details on which compiler you are using?

Answer (score 3):

```
int array[x];
```

`x` is not a compile time constant and the compiler is complaining about it. Variable Length Arrays are part of C99 standard. Looks like your compiler is not adhering to the standard.

You can use `malloc` to dynamically allocate the array and later `free` it. Or use a compiler that supports VLA.

Comment: Wrong, you can do this in C99 as long as you are only declaring your variable -- it cannot be defined (initialized).

Comment: @JacobPollack Yes. By the time I wrote the edit, you made the comment.

Comment: +1 for fix. I still think it is useful to mention to the OP (and others) that this array cannot be defined, only declared.

Comment: I don't understand your terminology of declaration, definition in this context.

Comment: Declaring a variable is when you are stating that the given identifier is of a specific type, such as `int array[x]` -- saying `array` is an array of integers. Defining the variable is stating the given identifier is of a specific type **and** assigning it a value (through initialization), `int array[x] = { 0 }`. If he attempted to zero-fill using the array initialization syntax it would be *invalid*.

Comment: I'm using borland C++ through parallels desktop, apparently it shows no problem with xcode

Comment: @David If you are building in C++ mode variable length arrays were never allowed ... although a few compilers support it in C++ as an extension.

Comment: @JacobPollack Its not necessary to initialize a variable in order to define it. e.g- `int a;` is both definition and declaration but only in some cases the definition and declaration are different as in case of `extern` variables :)

Comment: @PHI, there is a lot of ambiguity between the two terms, I am yet to see a definition that does not vary from programmer to programmer. However, fair point (+1).

Answer (score 3):

This declaration:

```
int array[x];
```

is a [Variable length array(`VLA`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and it is a `C99` feature. Without `VLA` support array sizes must be compile time constants. This [`DrDobb's article`](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444) on `VLA` is a good reference.

You mentioned you were using both `Borland C++` and `Xcode`, as far as I can tell `Borland`s last version was [1997](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2012/11/28/42012) which would mean it is unlikely to support this feature although I can not find much info. If you are using a more modern branch of the tool it claims to suporrt C99 so there may be a way to enable support.

`Xcode` as far as I understand can use either `clang` or `gcc` both of which support `VLA` in `c99` mode, [`gcc supports VLA as an extension`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) in non-C99 mode and in C++ and [`clang supports this as well in limited cases`](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla)

If you need to develop in both compilers you may have to abandon `VLA` and use an alternative method for dynamically sized arrays such as `malloc` in C and in C++ `std::vector` is probably the right choice for many situations.

Comment: +1 For tailoring your response to his specific environment. Didn't see him mention that, dang SO notifications.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** *There is a lot of ambiguity with respect to the difference of the following two terms: "declaration" and "definition". Note the example I use to illustrate the difference if you happen to interpret the ambiguity differently than I do.*

---

For sake of completeness:

*Declaring* a variable length array ([VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) is entirely valid in C99, as you have done:

```
int n;

scanf( "%d", &n );

int arr[ n ];
```

... the issue is likely with the compiler you are using or the flags you have specified. An alternative approach is to use the memory pool and `malloc` a block of memory sufficiently large (`n * sizeof( int )`) then `free` the block of memory when you are done with it.

Going back to your original code, it is **very important** to remark that: only *declaring* a variable length array is valid, *defining* one is not. Say for example you wanted to declare a variable length array and zero-fill all of the elements. You could **not do the following**:

```
int n;

scanf( "%d", &n );

int arr[ n ] = { 0 }; // Invalid.
```

... as you are defining `arr`. You would need to do the following:

```
int n;

scanf( "%d", &n );

int arr[ n ]; // Valid.

// Zero-fills the array.
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  arr[ i ] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Defining  variable-length array is valid. Initializing it is not supported by the standard. This answer is confused about the terms. A declaration describes an identifier. A definition (for an object) also causes space to be reserved for an object. Initialization sets values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language:C -->
/*maybe you can like this*/
int x;
int *p;
printf("Enter the number of value to be Entered:");
scanf("%d", &x);
p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * x);

//p[0 - (x-1)] can be used
```

Comment: -1 for many reasons, including: already mentioned (your answer is a lesser quality answer and a subset of the other answers) and you have a bad example (do not cast `malloc`).